# “Entity already exists” error when writing unique records to Azure Table Storage (with Azure Function) Local Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-emulator

**EDIT:**
I've just tested this again pointing at a temporarily created table on real Azure, and that's worked fine whereas I could repeatedly get this to happen with the local Emulator. So I suspect this is a bug with the Emulator?

Anyone know anything about that?

---

Extremely similar to [Getting "Entity already exists" error writing aggregates to Azure Table Storage (with Azure Function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767899/getting-entity-already-exists-error-writing-aggregates-to-azure-table-storage) except that I've logged out all my records and I'm very confident that my code is generating unique Partition/Row Keys, which *don't* already exist in the Storage Table.

My insert code looks like this:

```cs
public static async Task BatchInsert<TEntity>(this CloudTable table, IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    where TEntity : TableEntity
{
    var entityPartitionGroups = entities.GroupBy(e => e.PartitionKey).ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll(entityPartitionGroups.Select(async partitionGroup =>
    {
        var batches = partitionGroup.Batch(BatchSize).Select(batch => batch.ToList()).ToList();
        foreach (var batchToInsert in batches)
        {
            var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
            foreach (var tableEntity in batchToInsert)
            {
                batchOperation.Insert(tableEntity);
            }

            try
            {
                var entitiesAsStrings = batchToInsert.Select((entity, i) => $"{i}: {entity.PartitionKey}, {entity.RowKey}").StringJoin(";");
                Debug.WriteLine("Writing: " + entitiesAsStrings);
                await table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
                Debug.WriteLine("Wrote: "+entitiesAsStrings);
            }
            catch (StorageException ex)
            {
                // break point here.
                throw new AzureTableBatchInsertException(batchToInsert, ex);
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

- I'm writing each Partition in parallel, to try to increase insert performance.
- Within each Partition, I write all the records in series; I use `.ExecuteBatchAsync()` to write batches of 100 records at a time.
- When I run this, with the debugger enabled, and a break point is set. I've also wiped the target table, which is in the local Storage emulator.
- Nothing else is running that could talk to the table.

So I'm starting from a blank slate, and looking at the logs and everything confirms that the records I'm putting in are unique, but I'm still getting the "Entity already exists" error. (It's accusing element `[0]` of being the problem, so it thinks the entire batch has already been written.)

When I hit the break point, and look the in the storage emulator (using MS Azure Storage Explorer) the records ARE present, despite an initially blank DB, and only 1 log record of attempting to write the record.

---

It seems a lot like sometimes `.ExecuteBatchAsync()` **retries** a batch, despite having successfully written it?

**What's going on here and how do I stop it from incorrectly throwing?**

---

*Happy to post the relevant portions of the Debug Output, but there's nothing at all interesting going on in it.*

Comment: I've just tested this again pointing at a temporarily created table on real Azure, and that's worked fine whereas I could repeatedly get this to happen with the local Emulator. So I suspect this is a bug with the Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

> I've just tested this again pointing at a temporarily created table on real Azure, and that's worked fine whereas I could repeatedly get this to happen with the local Emulator. So I suspect this is a bug with the Emulator?

As [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/408#issuecomment-279570009) said, when using  4.6 emulator and run with ExecuteBatchAsync, it will also get `EntityAlreadyExists` error message. So, this is an emulator issue.

We have released **Emulator v5.1 to resolve this issue**. Please give it a try to unblock.

Comment: The Emulator cmd-line "UI" reports itself as `Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool` :(